# Changing $locale in ui-router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internationalization, angular-ui-router, angular-ui-bootstrap

## What I want to achieve

In our angularjs we are using angular-ui-bootstrap for our datepickers. We want our datepickers to be localized in the user's locale but we cannot do that dynamically because there is not such API. The user's locale is retrieved from the backend so I need to change angular's locale before the main state is rendered. My solution to that is to call a service that would inject the correct locale file in our app.

## The code

The injectorService:

```
;(function(module) {
'use strict';

function injector($q) {
    var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
    return {
        addScript: function(url, async, cb) {
        return $q(function(resolve, reject) {
            var script = document.createElement('script');
            var loaded;
            script.type = 'text/javascript';
            script.setAttribute('src', url);
            script.onreadystatechange = script.onload = function() {
              if (!loaded) {
                if(cb && _.isFunction(cb)){
                    cb(null, 'ok');
                } else {
                    return resolve('ok');
                }
              }
              loaded = true;
              resolve('loaded');
            };
            script.onerror = function(error) {
                if(!error.isTrusted){
                    if(cb && _.isFunction(cb)){
                        cb(error, null);
                    } else {
                        reject(error);
                    }
                } 
            };
            body.appendChild(script);
        });
    }
  };
}

module.factory('Injector', injector);

}(angular.module('injector', [])));
```

In the the initiation of the main state I call the following code in the resolve section

```
            resolve: {
                    env : function(userService, Injector) {
                        return userService.getLocale()
                            .then(function(env) {
                                var userEnv = env;
                                var baseUrl = '/app/';
                                var angularSpecificLocale = '';

                                switch(userEnv.userlocale){
                                    case 'fr':  
                                  angularSpecificLocale = baseUrl + 'fr.js';
                                    break;
                                case 'ro':
                                  angularSpecificLocale = baseUrl + 'ro.js';
                                    break;
                                default:
                                  angularSpecificLocale = 'en';
                                  break;
                                }
                                // Don't add any locale files
                                if(angularSpecificLocale === 'en'){
                                    return userEnv;
                                } else {
                                  return Injector.addScript(angularSpecificLocale)
                                    .then(function() {
                                        return userEnv;
                                    });
                                }
                            });
                    }
                }
```

## The problem

The problem is that the datepicker is still not localized. I think I'm missing the last step here because when I add this snippet in my code

```
angular.injector(['ngLocale']).get('$locale')
```

I see that the locale id is correct. I would appreciate some help without using any external library

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I am using [angularDeferredBootstrap](https://github.com/philippd/angular-deferred-bootstrap) module for that purpose:

```
deferredBootstrapper.bootstrap({
    element: document.body,
    module: 'frontApp',
    resolve: {
        userLang: ['$http', function ($http) {
            return $http.get('/api/userLanguage');
        }]
    }
});
```

Then you can inject and use `userLang` anywhere in your application

Comment: Thanx for the reply! I would prefer a solution without having to add one more library in my project, especially now that i think i'm really close to the solution :)